# Issue while reading raw satellite data using GDAL Python

Tags: python, gdal

I have a raw satellite imagery (non-georeferenced). I am trying to read this raw data (.L-4 file) (3 bands) using GDAL using the following code:

```
from osgeo import gdal

src_ds = gdal.Open( "INPUT.L-4" )

img_bands = []

for band in range( src_ds.RasterCount ):
    band += 1
    print ("[ GETTING BAND ]: ", band)
    srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(band)

    img_bands.append(srcband.ReadAsArray())
```

Now with this above code I am able to read the raw image. But the issue is: In the list, 3 elements are getting appended but only first 2 elements are showing as array type while the third element is showing as "NoneType".

Why is one band coming as NoneType and not as an array?

Comment: please remove the statistics stuff if that has no effect on the problem. does it also give you NoneTzpe if you access the band direclty, not after the others in a loop?

Comment: Yes I am getting NoneType when I am trying to read the band directly as an array (happening with band 3). But when I am opening the raw image in ArcGIS all the 3 bands are getting displayed.